# Best way to load data with AJAX in Drupal 7

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

What is the best way to load async data in Drupal 7?

Curriently I'm loading my data with jQuery with my own nodes. I have build an own menu_hook which is aviable under `/events` and e.g. `/events/2012-04-17` this page is also aviable for normal browsing. I check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is set if it is I return the data in a JSON string and parse the data.

Can I run in some trouble if I activate some caching technics? Or is there a better way to load the data? It seems that this does not work with boost because I'm killing the script with `die()` what could I do else?

```
function my_module_menu() {
    $items['events'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'event_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
    $items['events/%date'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'event_page',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB,
    );
    return $items;
}

function event_page($date=null) {
    $build=array();
    // add some other "controls"
    $build['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save'),
    );

    if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 'XMLHttpRequest' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?json')!==FALSE) {
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Content-type: application/json', true);
        $json=loadData();
        die(json_encode($json));
    }

    return $build;
}
```

Comment: @NikhilMohan AFIK is [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) an alias for exit isn't it?

Comment: Just a note for other you need also to send the Vary Headers so avoid that the browser shows a cached json response instead to the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [drupal_json_output](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) instead, this will automatically change the headers so no exit() is required.

Another option would be to change the delivery callback on that particular path combined with the data from $_SERVER using [hook_page_delivery_callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_delivery_callback_alter/7) and then return a valid array for the page using [ajax_command](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7)'s.

The first option is alot easier, I've never tried the second one myself but it might be too much for your situation. Unfortunately I don't know how either of these techniques behaves together with boost but hopefully one of them will work.

Comment: Well I found this option too. But the output is not cached.